# Error with PhantomJS when build Jhispter 3.2 application

Tags: maven, phantomjs, jhipster

In my **Jhispter 3.2.0** application (springboot + angularjs) when I run

`mvn package -Pprod -Dmaven.test.skip=false`

I have the following error with the PhantomJS test :

```
  [INFO] --------------------------------------
24-mai-2016 10:49:06    [INFO]          GULP TEST --NO-COLOR
24-mai-2016 10:49:06    [INFO] --------------------------------------
24-mai-2016 10:49:12    [10:49:12] Using gulpfile /home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/BAC2-BB-JOB1/gulpfile.js
24-mai-2016 10:49:12    [10:49:12] Finished 'wiredep:test' after 160 ms
24-mai-2016 10:49:12    [10:49:12] Starting 'test'...
24-mai-2016 10:49:16    24 05 2016 10:49:16.033:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
24-mai-2016 10:49:16    24 05 2016 10:49:16.038:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    24 05 2016 10:49:17.225:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#39xT4ekwBtS29U-sAAAA with id 54555652
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
24-mai-2016 10:49:17      TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'angular.module('backTrocApp').component('jhiAlertError',jhiAlertError)')
24-mai-2016 10:49:17      at /home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/BAC2-BB-JOB1/src/main/webapp/app/components/alert/alert-error.directive.js:9
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.47 secs / 0 secs)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
24-mai-2016 10:49:17      TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'angular.module('backTrocApp').component('jhiAlert',jhiAlert)')
24-mai-2016 10:49:17      at /home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/BAC2-BB-JOB1/src/main/webapp/app/components/alert/alert.directive.js:9
  24-mai-2016 10:49:17  
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.475 secs / 0 secs)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    Missing error handler on `socket`.
24-mai-2016 10:49:17    TypeError: Cannot read property '54555652' of null
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at onBrowserComplete (/home/bamboo-home/xml-JOB1/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at /home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/BAC2-BB-JOB1/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at finish (/home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/BAC2-BB-JOB1/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at Server.<anonymous> (/home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/BAC2-BB-JOB1/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:347:9)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
24-mai-2016 10:49:17        at emitCloseNT (net.js:1521:8)
 24-mai-2016 10:53:17       var suite = suites[browser.id];
24-mai-2016 10:53:17    TypeError: Cannot read property '54555652' of null
24-mai-2016 10:53:17    24 05 2016 10:53:17.782:WARN [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 240000 ms.
24-mai-2016 10:53:17    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you running node LTS version as we recommend in our doc? What does `node -v` print?

Comment: I'm running v4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this jhipster [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3521)

As you said you are using Jhipster v 3.1.0, and this is added in 3.2.0, so try to update your application and try again.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the reason, the test are running with angular 1.4 and produce error.

I don't remember but for the **angular-ui-tree** plugin i change in my bower.json angular to 1.2.0 instead 1.5.0

```
"resolutions": {
"angular": ">1.2.0"
}
```

All is working (same the angular-ui-tree), thx for help